# List not taking strings managed with regex correctly

Tags: c, regex, string, file, list

I'm trying to make this code work. It has to take a line from a text file, use regex to catch the information I need (IP,Date,"request" and code). The regex system work, and I have all the strings like I want at the end of the while cycle. But when I try to assign them to the strings in the results list, and try to print them everything goes mad.

This is an example of the lines I have manage:
"46.252.157.14 - - [18/Dec/2013:00:00:01 +0100] "GET /f0?fid=21&os=0&cdl=0&id=SOR HTTP/1.1" 200 17823";

```
This is the output:
Line: 1 IP:46.252.157.14
         Data:[18/Dec/2013:00:00:01 +0100]
         REQ:"GET /f0?fid=21&os=0&cdl=0&id=SOR HTTP/1.1
         COD: 200 

Print List:

IP: 46.252.157.14 - - [18/Dec/2013:00:00:01 +0100] "GET /f0?fid=21&os=0&cdl=0&id=SOR   HTTP/1.1" 200 
Data: [18/Dec/2013:00:00:01 +0100] "GET /f0?fid=21&os=0&cdl=0&id=SOR HTTP/1.1" 200 
Req: "GET /f0?fid=21&os=0&cdl=0&id=SOR HTTP/1.1" 200 
Cod:  200 

IP: (null)
Data: (null)
Req: (null)
Cod: (null)
```

As you can see, the strings are all printed correctly, the problem comes in when I try to print the strings in the list.

And this is the code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <regex.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct results{
    char* IP;
    char* Data;
    char* Req;
    char* cod;
    struct results* next;
    struct results* back;
};
typedef struct results results;

regex_t regex_ip;
regex_t regex_data;
regex_t regex_req;
regex_t regex_cod;

char* regex_ip_re= "^[0-9]*[.][0-9]*[.][0-9]*[.][0-9]*";
char* regex_data_re="\\[.*?\\]";
char* regex_req_re="(\".*?)\"";
char* regex_cod_re="\\s[0-9]{3}\\s";
char* line=NULL;



char* match(regex_t* r,char* to_match){
    char* result;
    regmatch_t regmatch[strlen(line)];
    if (regexec(r, to_match, strlen(line),regmatch, 0) == 0)
    {
      int g = 0;
      for (g = 0; g < strlen(line); g++)
        {
          if (regmatch[g].rm_so == (size_t)-1)
            break;  // No more groups

          char sourceCopy[strlen(to_match) + 1];
          strcpy(sourceCopy, to_match);
          sourceCopy[regmatch[g].rm_eo] = 0;
          result=sourceCopy+regmatch[g].rm_so;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

void createnode(results* node){
    results *temp=malloc(sizeof(results));
    temp->next=NULL;
    temp->back=node;
    node->next=temp;
}

int main(){
    regcomp(&regex_ip,regex_ip_re, REG_EXTENDED|REG_NEWLINE);
    regcomp(&regex_data,regex_data_re, REG_EXTENDED|REG_NEWLINE);
    regcomp(&regex_req,regex_req_re,REG_EXTENDED|REG_NEWLINE);
    regcomp(&regex_cod,regex_cod_re,REG_EXTENDED|REG_NEWLINE);

    FILE *log;
    char* IP=;char* DATA;char* REQ;char* COD;
    results *output=malloc(sizeof(results));
    results *head=output;
    size_t len=NULL;
    log=fopen("./log.txt","r");
    FILE *out=fopen("./output.txt","a");
    int linenum=1;

    //This is where i think the problem is:
    while(!feof(log)&&linenum<2){
        getline(&line,&len,log);

            IP=match(&regex_ip,line);
            printf("Line: %d IP:%s\n",linenum,IP);
            output->IP=IP;

            DATA=match(&regex_data,line);
            printf("         Data:%s\n",DATA);
            output->Data=DATA;

            REQ=match(&regex_req,line);
            printf("         REQ:%s\n",REQ);
            output->Req=REQ;

            COD=match(&regex_cod,line);
            printf("         COD:%s\n",COD);;
            output->cod=COD;

            linenum++;
            createnode(output);
            output=output->next;
    }
    output=head;
    printf("\nPrint List:\n\n");
    while(output!=NULL){
        printf("IP: %s\nData: %s\nReq: %s\nCod:
    %s\n\n",output->IP,output->Data,output->Req,output->cod);
        output=output->next;
    }





    return 0;
}
```

I tried to be as clear as I could and reported the entire code even if I think that the problem is just with the list. Sorry if it's hard to read.

Thank you ;)

edit, final result:

Declaration of the list.

```
struct results{
    char IP[15];
    char Data[30];
    char Req[700];
    char cod[5];
    struct results* succ;
    struct results* prec;
};
typedef struct results results;
```

and this is the while

```
while(!feof(log)){
        getline(&line,&len,log);
        strcpy(output->IP,match(&regex_ip,line));
        strcpy(output->Data,match(&regex_data,line));
        strcpy(output->Req,match(&regex_req,line));
        strcpy(output->cod,match(&regex_cod,line));
        linenum++;
        creanodo(output);
        output=output->succ;
}
return testa;
```

}

Comment: I didn't know C allows = sign as part of variable name `char* IP=;`, might mess up the parser, no?

Comment: @sln At least under clang thats an error when compiling. `error: expected expression`

Comment: Even though you've fixed it with a malloc in the match function, be sure to free all that space before exiting.

Comment: Btw, anybody know what regex engine is being used here?

Comment: i think it's posix...if we're talking about the same thing ;).
I added the actual state of the code, any suggestion/comment? Keep in mind that that list is made of around 9000 nodes with this input file.

Comment: Its been so long since I'd done C. Here goes.. Just so you know, based on the regex for these (regex_data, regex_req) `Data[30]` and `Req[700]`, the buffers can overrun, causing a page fault. It might be a pain, but malloc for these is the only way to make it bullet-proof. Also, I can't remember if 'C' had a 'string' type that does its own memory management. I think only C++, not sure. But that would be the way to go as well.

Comment: Example:  string Data; string Req;

Comment: First of all thank you  for your help :) . I think i havent understood what you said. The char arrays are used just for storing the resulting strings, which are obtained from the regexec processing that uses char pointers. The problem is with those char pointers? No there isn t a string type in c.

Comment: Well, now that I re-look at the regular expressions you are using, there are 3 'un-bounded' ones. That means ones with the `*` quantifiers (where `.*?` is notorious). That tells the engine to match as 'many' as possible (greedy has nothing to do with this possibility). The result is that in the `strcpy()`, the matched text (source) could overrun the destination buffer (output->Data). Probably won't happen, but its possible if you have ill-formed data.

Comment: char* regex_ip_re= "^[0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}";
char* regex_data_re="\\[.{26}\\]";
char* regex_req_re="(\".*?)\"";
This is the best precision i could get. I just started using regex, so i can't make them complex. Also, i think C doesn't have full regex support, as most of "special characters" seem to not be working. Again, thank you for the support ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're storing pointers to transient C strings (`sourceCopy`) which fall out of scope.

Accessing them later is UB.

Create a copy of the strings (malloc+strcpy), then store these in your list.